# getting data from newly created row in table

Tags: angular, typescript, x-editable

After getting data from the `json` file, I am assigning the data to the array present in the component and looping that array into the table using `*ngFor`.
Now I've have a button, using which I'm adding a row into the table (actually adding an object into the array that is binded with table) with empty fields. Here I am using `<x-editable>` component that will edit the data from empty to something meaningful in the table. And after editing, I want to store the data into the `newAttr` object present in the component. But how to bind the data of the `td` with the `newAttr` object. Hers's my code

app.component.html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Rank</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let d of data">
            <td><x-editable>{{d.id}}</x-editable></td>
            <td><x-editable>{{d.name}}</x-editable></td>
            <td><x-editable>{{d.rank}}</x-editable></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button (click)="addStudent()">Add A Student</button>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    data : any = [];
    newAttr : any = [];

    constructor(private http: Http){
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.http.get('./assets/students.json').subscribe(data=>{
            this.data = data.json().data;
        })
    }

    addStudent(){
        this.newAttr = {id:"empty",name:"empty",rank:"empty"};
        this.data.push(this.newAttr);
        this.newAttr = {};
    }

}
```

students.json (I don't think its needed but still...)

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "id":101,
            "name":"Andrew",
            "rank":3
        },{
            "id":102,
            "name":"Bob",
            "rank":5
        },{
            "id":103,
            "name":"James",
            "rank":1
        },{
            "id":104,
            "name":"Matthew",
            "rank":2
        },{
            "id":105,
            "name":"Kevin",
            "rank":4
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use **@Output()** decoration in your child component 

  **@Output() rowdata = new EventEmitter<any>();** and emit edit data like below

 **this.rowdata.emit(editdata);**

than use this @Output in your parent like 

<td><x-editable (rowdata)="geteditdata($event)">{{d.id}}</x-editable></td>

your child component edit data get in geteditdata() function like below

geteditdata(editdata){
//here you bind edit data in your newAttr object by unique id
}
```